# ¿ Diferencia entre arquitectura MVC y MPA?

Tags: javascript, arquitectura

Hola soy novato en este mundo y no sé cuál es la diferencia entre una arquitectura MVC y una MPA.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon todo lo que has encontrado en internet acerca de estos conceptos, y qué entiendes acerca de tales patrones. Recuerda que [es.so] debe ser _el último sitio al que debes acudir_. Lee [ask].

Comment: Hola Andrés, tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, stackoverflow es un sitio de preguntas especificas y problemas específicos de programación. Primero haz tu propia investigación y después reduce el alcance de la pregunta, si no, no te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.